# How to get rid of the background in Shading

Tags: world

I incidently did something while in the Shading window and now I have a background in "3D viewport". How do I go back and remove this world background?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen the *Shading* workspace:

[image]

By default it displays the default *Material Preview* HDRI, you can remove it in the *Viewport Shading panel > World Opacity* (and you can hide the 2 spheres in the *Viewport Overlays > HDRI Preview*), or simply go back into the *Layout* workspace:

[image]